# How to make asterisk to start playing sound when call is answered?

Tags: command-line-interface, asterisk, playback, freepbx

Hi and thanks for reading.
I have a FreePBX box working here for the last years and now i have Zabbix monitoring some servers. So i want that zabbix use freepbx (asterisk) to call me if something is wrong.
I have tried to make a call from asterisk CLI, and it works, but the Playback application start playing before i answer the call. So when the sound finishes, the call finishes too. I need that the sounds starts when i answer the call and (if it's possible) it make a loop, playing once and once again until i hangup.
The command:

```
channel originate DAHDI/4/156XXXXXXX application Playback abandon-all-hope
```

I'm a newbie at Asterisk...
And sorry about my poor english.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That mean your dahdi channel setuped incorrect and asnwer call imidiatly, not when you answer your phone(ring detection not work).

You should consult your card manual and manuals in internet, how to setup dahdi card is not question for SO.

Sorry, no other way.

Comment: Thanks for reply, arheops. Can you give me a hint? Which file can i edit to reconfigure this? Remember that this is a freepbx box, so i can configure it from web interface too.

Comment: /etc/dahdi/dahdi.conf, /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf

Comment: Thank you, so much.